# How do I return Vue resource without putting to data?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, vue.js

I want to return result directly (Normally we try to put to data and access that data yeah. but now how I want is directly). Like when we call `hello()` function I want to return `result` variable. 
I try like the following, but it doesn't return yeah. How do I try?

```
    hello: function() {
        var result = "";

        this.$http.get(window.location.href).success(function(data) {
            result = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, request) {

        });            

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't return the data because the request is async. Your method sets up the request and then returns immediately, synchronously, before the request had a chance to assign any data to the `result` variable.

You can try to change your code slightly:

```
    hello: function() {
        var result = {};

        this.$http.get(window.location.href).success(function(data) {
            result.data = data;
            result.ready = true;
        }).error(function (data, status, request) {

        });            

        return result;
    }
```

That should enable you to access the data elsewhere (as `result.data`), but *only after the async query has succeeded*. The `result.ready` flag would tell you if and when that has happened.

In my opinion, it would definitely be better to work with promises, though, e.g. using [jQuery Deferreds and promises](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), or [ES6 promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) along with a [polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise).

Comment: You're much better simply working with the returned resource and then doing what you need when done. Waiting on result to be populated will be eroneous.